# How can I Gmail batch api call success in .NET with HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, gmail-api, mixed-content

I requested Gmail Batch API to postman and received the results normally.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS6f1.png)

So, based on Postman, an error occurs when a call is made using the HTTP Client on .NET. Both access token and boundary are the same, but a 400 Bad Request occurs.

link : [google-batch-guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch)

```cs
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

var uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/batch/gmail/v1";
var access_token = "[google access token]"; // my access token

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", access_token);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "www.googleapis.com");

var multipartContent = new MultipartContent("mixed", "stackoverflow");

// request 1
var requestContent1 = new StringBuilder();
requestContent1.AppendLine("--stackoverflow");
requestContent1.AppendLine("Content-Type: application/http");
requestContent1.AppendLine();
requestContent1.AppendLine("GET /gmail/v1/users/me/messages/18ca8a5d1dc95d09?format=metadata");

var httpContent1 = new StringContent(requestContent1.ToString());
multipartContent.Add(httpContent1);

// request 2
var requestContent2 = new StringBuilder();
requestContent2.AppendLine("--stackoverflow");
requestContent2.AppendLine("Content-Type: application/http");
requestContent2.AppendLine();
requestContent2.AppendLine("GET /gmail/v1/users/me/messages/18c94521fefc62d3?format=metadata");

var httpContent2 = new StringContent(requestContent2.ToString());
multipartContent.Add(httpContent2);

// end 3
var requestContent3 = new StringBuilder();
requestContent3.AppendLine("--stackoverflow--");

var httpContent3 = new StringContent(requestContent3.ToString());
multipartContent.Add(httpContent3);

/*
--stackoverflow
Content-Type: application/http

GET /gmail/v1/users/me/messages/18ca8a5d1dc95d09?format=metadata
--stackoverflow
Content-Type: application/http

GET /gmail/v1/users/me/messages/18c94521fefc62d3?format=metadata
--stackoverflow--
*/

var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, multipartContent);

using var reader = new StreamReader(await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
var json = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

response message

```cs
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Failed to parse batch request, error: Failed in parsing HTTP headers: (1 bytes redacted). Received batch body: (0) bytes redacted",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

No other attempt was made because the error message was not clear.

Comment: The error says the request headers are invalid. You didn't post the entire POSTMAN request and even blurred parts of what you posted, so we can't guess what's wrong. Why don't you use Google's .NET client library? It supports both [Gmail](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/gmail/v1) and [batching](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/batch).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks comment. [link1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qxnw.png) [link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/995GD.png) this pictures is not blurred. I want to try the HTTP Client first.

Comment: The GMail client uses HttpClient too. The problem here is that the request you created is invalid, not HttpClient. You gain nothing by using raw requests except extra allocations for all those strings. The Google client knows how to call GMail *and* how to correctly batch API requests

Comment: The problem may well be that [StringBuilder.AppendLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.appendline?view=net-8.0) uses a different newline on Windows and Linux. On Windows it appends `\r\n` while on Linux it appends `\n`.